# Update HTML Page using XML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax

I am trying to update a website using AJAX.

In my html I used the
`span id="test1"` and `span id="test2"`.

However only the content of **test1** is showed and not the content of **test2** from the XML file. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong in my javascript below?

```
window.onload = function ShowAlert() {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
         // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "note.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("test1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("test2")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: what does your response look like?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? If span `test2` is inside span `test1` it will be overwritten by your second to last statement and hence cannot be used anymore - also console output and resulting dom would be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Since an error in the javascript does not jump out to me, I would recommend using an inspector, such as [DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to inspect `span id="test2"`
Perhaps the there is some other error (other than the javascript, possibly DOM structure) causing the data not to appear.